# how to read text (value) from jsf selectonelistbox itemLabel text?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, selectonelistbox

Below is my JSF

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="lstmonth"
required="true"
value="#{secdeal.month}">
<f:selectItem
    itemValue="JAN"
    itemLabel="01-January"/>
<f:selectItem
    itemValue="FEB"
    itemLabel="02-February"/>
<f:selectItem
    itemValue="MAR"
    itemLabel="03-March"/>
```

In javascript  (In same file)

I want to read the selecteditem's itemLabel's text. (i.e: If I select 01-January, I want the same text into my var x)

x=getElementById('Form:lstmonth').itemLabel // not working
x=getElementById('Form:lstmonth').innerText // not working -- returning all months

How to get the itemLabel text? please suggest

Actually I want **x=01-January** (selected item)

Comment: Is there any reason for Un-accepting the solution? Did it not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, it worked. By mistakenly i could have un accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("Form:lstmonth");
var selectedIndex = ele.selectedIndex;
var x = ele.options[selectedIndex].text;
```